# How to get Saturday's Date (Or any other weekday's Date)- SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime, date

How to get Saturday's Date. I have today's date with me.

```
GETDATE()
```

How to do this.

For eg. TODAY is `08-08-2011`

I want output as `08-13-2011`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a function that will return the next Saturday if you call it like this:

```
SELECT dbo.fn_Get_NextWeekDay('2011-08-08', 6)
```

The "6" comes from [the list of possible values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181598.aspx) you can set for `DATEFIRST`.

You can get any other day of the week by changing the second parameter accordingly.

This is the function:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.fn_Get_NextWeekDay') IS NOT NULL 
  DROP FUNCTION dbo.fn_Get_NextWeekDay
GO
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_Get_NextWeekDay(
     @aDate   DATETIME
   , @dayofweek      INT
    /*
      @dw - day of the week
      1 - Monday
      2 - Tuesday
      3 - Wednesday
      4 - Thursday
      5 - Friday
      6 - Saturday
      7 - Sunday
    */   
  )
RETURNS DATETIME 
AS
/*
  SELECT dbo.fn_Get_NextWeekDay('2011-08-08', 6)
  SELECT dbo.fn_Get_NextWeekDay('2011-08-08', 1)
*/
BEGIN
  RETURN 
      DATEADD(day
        , ( @dayofweek + 8 - DATEPART(dw, @aDate) - @@DATEFIRST ) % 7
        , @aDate 
      )  
END
GO
```

**[EDIT]**
This might be another solution. This should work in any language:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.fn_NextWeekDay') IS NOT NULL 
  DROP FUNCTION dbo.fn_NextWeekDay
GO
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_NextWeekDay(
     @aDate     DATE
   , @dayofweek NVARCHAR(30)
  )
RETURNS DATE
AS
/*
  SELECT dbo.fn_NextWeekDay('2016-12-14', 'fri')
  SELECT dbo.fn_NextWeekDay('2016-03-15', 'mon')
*/
BEGIN
  DECLARE @dx INT = 6
  WHILE UPPER(DATENAME(weekday,@aDate)) NOT LIKE UPPER(@dayofweek) + '%'
  BEGIN

    SET @aDate = DATEADD(day,1,@aDate)

    SET @dx=@dx-1
    if @dx < 0 
    BEGIN
      SET @aDate = NULL 
      BREAK
    END
  END

  RETURN @aDate

END
GO
```

Comment: This is great solution but is non-deterministic and will not work in any language.

Comment: For the value dbo.fn_Get_NextWeekDay('2016-12-14', 2) the function returns 2016-12-13 00:00:00.000 in some configurations

Answer (score 4):

```
DECLARE @Today date = 'TODAYS-DATE';
DECLARE @TodayNumber int = DATEPART(dw, @Today) -- Get the day number
DECLARE @Saturday date = DATEADD(DAY, (6-@TodayNumber)%7, @Today) 
-- Add the number of days between today and saturday (the 6th day), modulus 7 to stop you adding negative days
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Not sure, but I think this would not work if today's date is a sunday. EDIT: Never mind, turns out -1%7 yields -1 and not 1 as I expected.

Answer (score 3):

Use [DATEPART](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) to get the day of week of today and add the difference to the desired day of week to todays date.

Answer (score 3):

Use a Calendar table (table with one row per date):

```
SELECT MIN(DateValue) DateValue
FROM Calendar
WHERE DateValue >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
AND DayOfWeek = 'Saturday';
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach to this takes two steps, but might be more readable (look ma, no modulus):

1. Go back to last saturday: `DATEADD(DAY, -1 * datepart(weekday, GETDATE()), getdate())`
2. Then, add on a week: `DATEADD(WEEK, 1, @lastSaturday, getdate()))`

The whole thing:

```
declare @today DATETIME = GETDATE()
declare @lastSaturday DATETIME = DATEADD(DAY, -1 * datepart(weekday, @today), @today)
declare @nextSaturday DATETIME = DATEADD(WEEK, 1, @lastSaturday)
```

Or, if you're ok with `@today` being `GETDATE()`, you can do the calculation all at once:

```
SELECT DATEADD(WEEK, 1, DATEADD(DAY, -1 * datepart(weekday, GETDATE()), getdate()))
```

Comment: This solution however does not account for possible different configurations of @@DATEFIRST.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the SQL DATEADD function.

[DATEADD (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx)

Which you can use this along with DATEPART function to return the correct date.

[DATEPART (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
SET DATEFIRST 7
DECLARE @d DATETIME
SET @d = '2011-08-08' --GETDATE()

SELECT NEXT_SAT = DATEADD(day, (7  + @@DATEFIRST - DATEPART(dw, @d)) % 7, @d )
```

Comment: but `SET DATEFIRST 7` this cannot be used inside a SQL Function.. wht to do ?

Comment: what's your current value of the SET DATEFIRST ? ( select @@DATEFIRST )

Comment: current value is 7 . but it might change from SYSTEM to SYSTEM ..right ??

Comment: that's true, but you usually do not mess around with that value server-wide

Comment: yes... I got solution give this `SET DATEFIRST 7' line before that function is been called...mostly from the SP. :)

Comment: Check my other answer for a more generic solution ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6982061/how-to-get-saturdays-date-sql-server/6983664#6983664 )

Comment: @leoinfo let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2229/discussion-between-sreekumar-and-leoinfo)

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @Curdate date=( SELECT SWITCHOFFSET(SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(),'+05:30') )  
declare @nextsaturdaydate date=(select dateadd(d, 7-datepart(WEEKDAY, @CurDate),@Curdate))
select @nextsaturdaydate
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.