# how to get date of 1st week of current month

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I have to get/create date (date of first week) from the user input of day name
Examples-
         if  input saturday then date should be 7 (for current month 1st saturday)
         if input sunday then date 1 (current month 1st sunday)
I am having to use lot of logic to get the date but couldn't get exact output
any suggestions on how to come up with the SQL query for such a function ?

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Are you using MS SQL or MYSQL or SlinkySQL or what? [SAP_HANA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAP_HANA) anyone?

Comment: I am using sql server 2008 r2

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL*plus in Oracle then the code will be as :

```
select next_day(sysdate,'&d')-7 from dual;
```

If any update required please do inform.

okay i have a link hereby where you can understand this and try to do

[Your answer!!!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6982061/how-to-get-saturdays-date-or-any-other-weekdays-date-sql-server)

Comment: i am using sql server 2008 r2

Comment: [follow this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6982061/how-to-get-saturdays-date-or-any-other-weekdays-date-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

SELECT DATEPART(dw,DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, GETDATE()), 0))

input: if getdate() returns date in jan 2017 
output: 1

input:if getdate() returns date in jan 2017 
output: 4