# ORACLE Find Date ('DD-MON-YYYY') of a given weekday in the past 7 days

Tags: sql, oracle

i am trying to create a view that compares a SCHEDULE table that has values such as ('Daily', 'Wednesday', 'Tuesday', etc..) and another table (REPORT CREATED) that is updated every day with dates (11-AUG-2017). Basically, if the Schedule table shows Daily, then the Report Created table record value should be whatever sysdate (current date) is equal to. That said, I'm not sure how to find out what the most recent 'Wednesday' or 'Tuesday' is equal to. I did find a function for SQL server ([How to get Saturday's Date (Or any other weekday's Date)- SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6982061/how-to-get-saturdays-date-or-any-other-weekdays-date-sql-server)) ; however, I do not understand how it works and can't find an equivalent in Oracle. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: I have created two sample tables:

Schedules Table:

```
Report_Name | Frequency
ORDERS_BY_DEPT | Daily
LOW_STOCK | Wednesday
INVENTORY_DISC | Thursday
```

and the Reports Table:

```
Report_Name | Create_Dt
INVENTORY_DISC | 3-Aug-2017
LOW_STOCK | 9-Aug-2017
ORDERS_BY_DEPT | 10-Aug-2017
```

So essentially, the Inventory_Disc report is off, since it should have ran every Thursday but hasn't been updated since last Thursday and the Orders_By_Dept report is off since it is a daily report and didn't run today.

Comment: Filter for the last 7 days, and use a join expression of weekdays...

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] - table data, expected output, etc.

Comment: can you add an example data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `NEXT_DAY( date_value, day_string )` function. Take the current day (`SYSDATE`) and subtract 7 days from it and then find the next day which matches your required day-of-the-week.

So, to get the most recent Wednesday:

```
SELECT NEXT_DAY( TRUNC( SYSDATE ) - 7, 'WEDNESDAY' )
FROM DUAL
```

Comment: That's a better approach :)

Comment: @MT0 Thank you for this response.  I believe this is definitely the direction to head.  That said, when I do this, I receive an error.  My SQL is:   SELECT a.report_name, CASE a.frequency WHEN 'Daily' THEN TRUNC(SYSDATE) ELSE NEXT_DAY(SYSDATE - 7, a.frequency) END expected_dt, b.create_dt from schedule a LEFT OUTER JOIN reports b on (A.report_name = b.report_name);  When I run this, I get the error: ORA-00932, inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got DATE and the line/column points to the a.frequency in the NEXT_DAY function.

Comment: That said, the a.frequency columns is varchar2, so I'm not sure how its being recognized as a date

Answer (score 0):

You can find the [day of the week](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#i34510) with:

```
to_char(sysdate, 'D')
```

So for example, the last Thursday is:

```
select  case 
        when to_char(sysdate, 'D') < 4 then sysdate - to_char(sysdate, 'D') - 7 + 4
        else sysdate - to_char(sysdate, 'D') + 4
        end
from    dual
```

Comment: `TO_CHAR( date, 'D' )` is dependent on the `NLS_TERRITORY` settings and will give different results depending on where in the world it is run. `ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TERRITORY='AMERICA'; SELECT TO_CHAR( DATE '2017-08-11', 'D' ) FROM DUAL;` outputs `6` but if you do  `ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TERRITORY='UNITED KINGDOM';` then it outputs `5`. You will also run into issues if today is Monday and you want the previous Tuesday as you need to go back to the previous week.

Comment: @MT0: Agree, it requires the local day number (5 for the Thursday in the USA). The `case` should deal with the last week correctly.  `next_day()` is the better option though